# Error in Makefile with echo without quotation marks

Tags: windows, makefile, echo

Recently I started getting error **make: execvp: echo: File or path name too long** on lines as **echo word1 word2** but not on lines with enclosing quotes **echo "word1 word2"**.

Why did I start to get these errors only now and not before? How to stop getting these errors?

Our company uses a lot of makefiles to compile c++ project with Visual Studio or gcc, and I don't like the idea to add quotation marks to all the existing Makefiles. I am currently running the makefiles from Visual Studio 2015/2017 command prompt.

Comment: Do you know what `word1` and `word2` are? Have you tried those `echo` commands on the command line?

Comment: I find it very surprising that make invoked on windows would give an error like that.  Are you using the Cygwin version of GNU make?  You should make that clear as that version is maintained by the Cygwin team and has a few changes from the standard GNU make.  Honestly I can't explain your problem.  I can think of no reason why _adding_ quotes (I assume you mean quotes not braces) would cause you to get an error about path too long, if there's nothing else different about those commands.

Comment: Beta: it is just that. echo word1 word2 on command line works fine. Any echoed words causes the problem.

MadScientist: I use GNU Make 3.81 which comes with MinGW in package msys-make. I meant quotes not braces, sorry. Also, the same problem happens with command mkdir (and probably more commands) if folder name is not enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Do you have special characters (like `*`, for instance) in your words?

Comment: No I don't. Simple example to reproduce my problem is line:
echo word
while this works:
echo "word"

Comment: I have reinstalled MinGW and problem persists.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that this problem involves some Win32 (or maybe 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit platform?) binary compatibility havocs. I remember getting these type of errors back in the day when running on the Windows-XP command line because Windows tried to emulate true 64K command line buffers etc...